# How to remove date created in blog post url for pyrocms (codeigniter)

Tags: codeigniter, url, routes, friendly-url, pyrocms

This may or may not have been answered. Since i've been searching for a correct answer the last few days, i'm afraid not. I'm working on this project in codeigniter (pyrocms) and i'm trying to get clean urls. I already managed to remove /index.php/ from the url. Except the blog module builds the urls from the date the post have been created (www.sitename.com/year/month/post-title. Obviously i want to achieve a url like www.sitename.com/post-title.

I tried routing in the module/blog/config/routes.php but that dind't work out for me as well.

Any help in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using PyroCMS v2x

`www.sitename.com/post-title` is going to be controlled by your pages controller.  It's a special thing the core dev team wrote in.

The blog is a module so `www.sitename.com/module_name/...` is how you call the module.

You *can* shorten the URL for the blog by editing the routing control in the blog module.

You could, at best, get away with `www.sitename.com/blog/title`, but you'll need to rewrite some of the module code and routing to do that.   There's no easy way to do it like you might find in wordpress.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! i'm indeed using PyroCMS v2.2. So isn't there any other way, like for example by using .htaccess?